# InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Build'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

My project base on net6.0 was working fine with IIS launch setting but when i added serivce

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

It stop working on IIS but Working on IIS Express and Self host.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add this configuration setting to your .csproj file and then republish your site to the server.

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
```

Comment: what it will do?

Comment: This is related to your .net.

Comment: See this thread for background info: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38892